# How to forward calls from my remote host to my local one

Tags: putty, iptables, forwarding, nat

I wish all calls to my_remote_host:port to be redirected to my_local_host:port, where my remote host is Linux and my local host is Windwos

Answer (score 0):

Open File C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1   my_local_host

Comment: Thanks, but I want this to be configured on my remote host, with something like nat, forwarding etc...